# Finding an explicit bijection between two open intervals

Tags: calculus, functions

Homework problem I'm having trouble with: find an explicit bijection $f: (20,21) \rightarrow (17,76).$ (open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$)

I tried to find the equation of a line between these two points in the XY plane and got $f(x) = \frac{-55}{3}x+ \frac{1163}{3}$, but this wasn't correct.

Is simply finding the equation of a line here the best approach? If so, what did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  the scale factor is $59$

Comment: $(20,21)$ and $(17,76)$ aren’t points, they are open intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than finding a map taking $20$ to $21$ and $17$ to $76$,

you should find a map taking $20$ to $17$ and $21$ to $76$.

The scale factor is $\dfrac{76-17}{21-20}=59$, so the answer is $f(x)=59(x-20)+17$,

which I leave to you to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a linear function is probably the best tactic. We want the following points to be on the line: $(20, 17)$ and $(21, 76)$. We calculate the slope as $\frac{76 - 17}{21 - 20} = \frac{59}{1} = 59$. Then the equation is $f(x) = 59(x - 20) + 17$, using point-slope.

Edit: If we want a continuous mapping from $(20, 21)$ to $(17, 76)$, it makes sense to try to send the endpoints to the endpoints.

We now show that the defined $f$ is in fact a function $f : (20, 21) \to (17, 76)$.

Suppose $x \in (20, 21)$. Then $20 < x < 21$. Then $0 < x - 20 < 1$. Then $0 < 59 (x - 20) < 59(1) = 59$. Then $0 + 17 < 59(x - 20) < 59 + 17$. Then $17 < 59(x - 20) < 76$. Then $f(x) \in (17, 76)$ as required.

We now show $f$ is injective. Suppose $x, y \in (20, 21)$ and $f(x) = f(y)$. Then $59(x - 20) + 17 = 59(y - 20) + 17$. Subtracting 17 from both sides gives us $59(x - 20) = 59(y - 20)$. Dividing both sides by 59 gives us $x - 20 = y - 20$. Adding 20 to both sides gives us $x = y$. Then $f$ is indeed injective.

We now show that $f$ is surjective. Suppose we have some $y \in (17, 76)$. Then $17 < y < 76$. Then $0 < y - 17 < 59$. Then $0 < \frac{y - 17}{59} < 1$. Then $20 < \frac{y - 17}{59} + 20 < 21$. Let $x = \frac{y - 17}{59} + 20$. Then $x \in (20, 21)$. And we have $f(x) = 59((\frac{y - 17}{59} + 20) - 20) + 17 = y$. Thus, we see that $f$ is surjective.

Then $f$ is a bijection.

As you can see, it's critical that we map the endpoints 20 and 21 to the endpoints 17 and 76 for our proofs.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why the points we want on the line are (20,17) and (21,76)? I think that's the part I was missing.

Comment: You don’t technically need to have those points, but you have to map the open interval (20,21) to the open interval (17,76), so the most straightforward way is to map 20 to 17 and 21 to 76, and every point in between according to the line that defines. You could also map 20 to 76 and 21 to 17, and every point in between according to that line. In fact, you could use any bijection, not just a line. Since your function doesn’t need to be continuous, the bijection doesn’t even need to be monotone.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus I've fleshed out the answer more. It should be clearer why I did things the way I did them.